# What is the definition of entropy in microcanonical ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am going through **Statistical Mechanics** book by *Kerson Huang* and he defines the entropy as,
$$S(E, V) = k_B \log \Gamma(E)$$
where $\Gamma(E)$ is the volume in phase space occupied by the microcanonical ensemble,
$$\Gamma(E) = \int_{E<\mathcal{H}(p,q)<E+\Delta}\ d^{3N}p\ d^{3N}q$$
All other books I've studied on Statistical Mechanics define entropy as,
$$S = k_B \log\Omega$$
where $\Omega$ is defined as the number of accessible microstates corresponding to the given energy between $E$ and $E+\Delta$. My understanding is that these two definitions will be equivalent to each other only if,
$$\Gamma(E) = \int_{E<\mathcal{H}(p,q)<E+\Delta}\ d^{3N}p\ d^{3N}q\ \rho(q, p, t)$$
where $\rho$ is the density function and therefore, $d^{3N}p\ d^{3N}q\ \rho(q, p, t)$ will represent the total number of accessible microstates in the phase space volume $d^{3N}p\ d^{3N}q$. So, please explain how these two seemingly different definitions do not contradict each other. What am I missing?

Comment: There is no contradiction: $\rho(q,p)$ is equal to a positive constant for all configurations with energy in the interval and to zero for the other ones. See the "postulate of equal a priori probability", equation (6.7) in the book (second edition). This postulate *defines* the microcanonical ensemble.

Comment: @Yvan, if $\rho$ is a constant, then the value of $\Gamma(E)$ would be proportional to the number of accessible microstates, not equal.

Comment: It does not matter, the thermodynamic entropy is defined only up to a constant.

Comment: (Moreover, what do you actually mean by "the number of accessible microstates" when discussing a classical system? The energy shell is made of a continuum of distinct microstates.)

Comment: Number of accessible microstates is the total number of points in the phase space enclosed in the volume $E$ and $E+\Delta$. So, I reasoned like, the higher the volume, the larger the number of points and the number of points should be the density of points times the volume.

Comment: The energy shell is a continuum: it contains infinitely many points. Of course, you might decide to discretize the phase space (that is, introduce small cells), but the scale you choose would be completely arbitrary (at least in a classical system). So, again, you cannot avoid introducing an arbitrary multiplicative constant (which becomes a harmless additive constant after taking the logarithm).

Comment: Oh, that is why we choose to divide the phase space into small chunks of volume like $\delta p\delta q = h_0$, where $h_0$ is small. This makes it all clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The density $\rho$ would count the number of microstates within the volume $d^{3N}p\,d^{3N}q$ that satisfies the energy constraint $E<\mathcal{H}<E+\Delta$. So you'd actually have:

\begin{align}
\Gamma(E) &= \int_{E<\mathcal{H}<E+\Delta} d^{3N}p\,d^{3N}q \\
&= \int \rho\,d^{3N}p\,d^{3N}q
\end{align}